# Convert numeric string to sqldbtype

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim MyType as String = "numeric"
Dim sdtype As SqlDbType  sdtype = DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(SqlDbType), MyType), SqlDbType)
```

Not working for numeric. I want to know how to handle this data types. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SqlDbType` enumeration simply does not contain the value "numeric" so it's not possible to cast such string to that enum.

To avoid error, use such code: (C#, not familiar with VB.NET sorry)

```
SqlDbType dbType;
if (Enum.TryParse<SqlDbType>(myType, true, out dbType))
{
    MessageBox.Show("type: " + dbType);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("invalid type: " + myType);
}
```

There are various numeric types available though, e.g. `Float` so changing the string to one of those should work just fine:

```
Dim MyType as String = "float"
```

All available data types for SQL Server database provider  are:

```
BigInt
Binary
Bit
Char
DateTime
Decimal
Float
Image
Int
Money
NChar
NText
NVarChar
Real
UniqueIdentifier
SmallDateTime
SmallInt
SmallMoney
Text
Timestamp
TinyInt
VarBinary
VarChar
Variant
Xml
Udt
Structured
Date
Time
DateTime2
DateTimeOffset
```

Any attempt to cast string not in this list will result in error.

**Edit**: on second thought looks like you are working with Access database? In such case, use `OleDbType` and not `SqlDbType`, just change the code to:

```
Dim sdtype As OleDbType  sdtype = DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(OleDbType), MyType), OleDbType)
```

And it should work, since `OleDbType` does contain "Numeric".

Comment: can you plaese tell me what are the other data types whose defination is not present in SqlDbType enum.

Comment: Not really, I can only tell what **is** present. Anyway, see my edit I think I figured the source of your problem.